# Rails console equivalent with play framework 2.4.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm used to work on Ruby on Rails projects and to use the `rails console` command to test all my models before doing anything else. I've recently switched to the Play Framework 2.4.x due to some choices made where I work.

I'm searching for an equivalent of this console to test my models with the database I provided inside the `application.conf` (`db.default.url`). How can I do this ?

Little bonus question : if it exists, is there any way to integrate it with IntelliJ ?

Answer (score 1):

Try running app from play console, should load all configs

[Play framework 2.0 console](https://playlatam.wordpress.com/2012/04/01/play-framework-2-quicktip-interactively-play-with-your-application-from-the-scala-console/)

In InteliJ, `play console` should be found under 'tools'

[Play console in InteliJ](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/01/play-console-in-intellij-idea/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're managing your project with SBT then you'll should be able to run `sbt console` which is similar to the rails console, but different.

Check out the twitter Scala school tutorial:
https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/sbt.html

Also note that the sbt console will not load your classes automatically like Rails does, you have to import any class you'll be using manually.